# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientAdapterFactory

Tags: java, svn, ant, noclassdeffounderror

Hi I am working with IBM message broker and SVN
I am trying to extract some code from SVN using ant. I have constructed my build file and using ant to run it but when I execute ant it gives me this error. Can anyone suggest me why I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientAdapterFactory
```

I am using IBM message broker inbuilt ant version 1.6.5
and java 1.6.0_06 this Java is also from IBM
I have my java and ant environmental variables working and my ant lib in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class was available when you compiled your source, but it isn't now you try to run your code.

You need to add the jar containing the class to your class path at runtime.  This is typically either with `-cp` or by creating a `Class-Path:` line in your MANIFEST.MF file, so you can use `-jar`.